# Cert C rules errors

Tags: klocwork, cert

We are checking code against cert rule and misra

I am getting: `cert C issue PORTING.CAST.SIZE`

```
void EDMADrv_setupChannel (uint8_t dmaChannel, const EDMADrv_TransferCfg* ptrTransferCfg)
{
    CSL_TpccRegs*      ptrEDMATPCCRegs;
    uint8_t                 tcc;
    uint16_t                paramId;
```

```
  paramId = (uint16_t)dmaChannel;//getting error from klocwork tool PORTING.CAST.SIZE ( Expression is cast to a type of potentially different size)
```

if assign

```
   uint16_t dmaChannelBit= dmaChannel;
   paramId = dmaChannelBit;
```

I get this error: `STRONG.TYPE.ASSIGN.INIT (: A strongly typed value 'dmaChannel' of type 'uint8_t' is assigned to the variable 'dmaChannelBit' of a different strong type 'uint16_t')`

can we ignore `STRONG.TYPE.ASSIGN.INIT` as we are assigning 8 bit to 16 bit .
Or is there any other solution?
can anyone tell if i ignore `STRONG.TYPE.ASSIGN.INIT` related issues .

Comment: Although tagged as `misra`, there is no MISRA violation reported here... `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are the same *essential type category*, and the assignment is to a *wider* type: therefore Rule 10.3 is not violated.  The cast is unnecessary, though.

Comment: I agree it is not a misra errors                                                                                             
 how to solve PORTING.CAST.SIZE cert rule for                                                 
 paramId = (uint16_t)dmaChannel

Comment: Well... `paramId = dmaChannel;` should be fine - standard integer promotion, which is well defined.  If this is still a problem, you need to get in touch with Klockwork support.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,I am same person who posted it .